# Syntax error in WordPress shortcode PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to register a WordPress shortcode.

I have a PHP return statement that includes HTML. Inside the HTML, I have a javascript onclick function. Visual Studio Code is throwing a syntax error which is, unexpected 'frame' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

I have read other articles on Stack Overflow and I have tried escaping single quotes that are inside the string but I could be inaccurately escaping. Below is some raw code without any escaping.

I understand the code below may not be pretty, but all help is appreciated nonetheless.

```
<?php
function torque_hello_world_shortcode() {
return '<div class="description pagecontent simple"></div>
<a onclick="document.getElementById('frame').style.display = document.getElementById('frame').style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'; return false;"><img class="someclass" src="#" alt="alt text" style="width:60px;height:60px;cursor:pointer !important;">
    <p class="something" style="cursor:pointer !important;">text! <span class="otherclass" style="cursor:pointer !important;">more text</span></p></a>
<div class="description pagecontent simple"></div>';
 }

add_shortcode( 'helloworld', 'torque_hello_world_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing single and double quotes in your return statement (on line 2 of the string, you basically close the string and follow it with the word "frame", without using concatenation or even the $ variable sign).

If you open a string with single quotes, a second single quote will close the string.  If you need to use single quotes **within** your string, you need to [escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) it, with a backslash: `echo 'Arnold once said: "I\'ll be back"';`
I added backslashes to your code:

```php
<?php
function torque_hello_world_shortcode() {
  return '<div class="description pagecontent simple"></div>
    <a onclick="document.getElementById(\'frame\').style.display = 
    document.getElementById(\'frame\').style.display == \'none\' ? \'block\' : 
    \'none\'; return false;"><img class="someclass" src="#" alt="alt text" 
    style="width:60px;height:60px;cursor:pointer !important;">
    <p class="something" style="cursor:pointer !important;">text! <span 
    class="otherclass" style="cursor:pointer !important;">more text</span></p></a>
    <div class="description pagecontent simple"></div>';
  }

add_shortcode( 'helloworld', 'torque_hello_world_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Thank you. Everything works. Can you tell me why in this string you don't need to escape the last " echo 'Arnold once said: "I\'ll be back(why not escape this one")';

Comment: Cause that's the closing quote.  A string has an opening and closing quote, always of the same type (single or double).  If you using single quotes to open and close your string, you can have double quotes within without escaping (and vice versa).  If you open & close with single quotes, and need single quotes within, you need to escape them with backslashes.